# Variável que recebe objeto de função em Python se torna esta função?

Tags: python

```
# Cria um objeto de uma funcao e este objeto a gente pode passar por ai
def add(a, b):
    return a + b


# "var" recebe o objeto da função add
var = add

print(id(add))  # 1332516488352
print(id(var))  # 1332516488352
print(type(add))  # <class 'function'>
print(type(var))  # <class 'function'>


# Aqui eu deleto a função criada
del add


# print(id(add)) Aqui da erro se eu imprimir obviamente
print(id(var))  # 1332516488352
# print(type(add))  Aqui da erro se eu imprimir obviamente
print(type(var))  # <class 'function'>
print(var(1, 3))  # 4
```

Minha dúvida:

- Quando eu crio a função `add` eu estou criando um objeto de uma função e a variável `add` guarda a referência para este objeto, esta explicação está correta?
- Pois seria a mesma lógica de uma variável `int` por exemplo? Se `x = 10`, `x` contém a referência para o objeto `10`?
- Entao quando eu faço `var` receber `add` e depois eu deleto `add`, na memória a função que seria o objeto continua existindo? E o que `var` faz é so guardar a referência para este objeto na memória?
- Entao se variável recebe uma função (`var = add`) e eu deleto a função (`del add`) `var` se torna a funcao `add`? Elas tem alguma diferença em si?
- Seria a mesma lógica do código abaixo?

```
# "A" guarda a referencia para o objeto 10
A = 10
# "B" recebe esta referencia 
B = A

print(id(A))  # 140727450395720
print(id(B))  # 140727450395720

del A

# Depois de eu deletar "A" o objeto "10" continua existindo na memoria e o B continua a apontar para este objeto 
#   e contendo o mesmo id de antes, entao o objeto em si nao foi modificado
print(id(B))  # 140727450395720
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Python, uma variável basicamente serve para vincular um nome a um determinado objeto - ver mais na [documentação, na seção "*Naming and binding*"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming). Este *link* diz que a definição de uma função (`def`) é um dos casos em que é feita esta vinculação.

Basicamente, ao fazer `def add(etc...)`, você está criando um objeto (a função), e associando ("binding") o nome `add` a ele. Outra forma de dizer a mesma coisa é "*`add` é uma referência ao objeto que representa a função*". Algo assim:

```
add ---> [função]
```

Isso quer dizer que `add` não é a função, é apenas um nome vinculado a ela. A função (o objeto) está lá, em algum lugar da memória, e `add` é apenas uma forma de acessá-lo (e usá-lo, manipulá-lo, etc).

Ao fazer `var = add`, você está associando o nome `var` ao mesmo objeto para o qual o nome `add` está associado (é feito o *binding*/vínculo/associação de `var` para o mesmo objeto para o qual `add` está *bound*/vinculado/associado). Então agora temos:

```
add ---> [função]
            ^
            |
var ________/
```

Ou seja, dois nomes associados ao mesmo objeto (no caso, a função). Ou "*duas variáveis apontando para o mesmo objeto*", "*duas referências para o mesmo objeto*", etc.

Ao fazer `del add`, você está removendo apenas o nome (a variável). Mas a função (o objeto que de fato contém o valor) continua existindo. Segundo a [documentação sobre `del`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement):

> *Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace*

Ou seja, apenas o nome é removido do escopo no qual ele está. O nome (a variável) `add` deixa de existir, mas o objeto para o qual ele apontava (a função) não é apagado. Portanto, depois do `del add`, ainda temos:

```
var ---> [função]
```

Então não é que `var` se torna a função. É que depois que `add` foi desvinculado, `var` ainda continuou vinculado ao objeto que representa a função. O objeto (a função) continua lá, ainda é o mesmo que foi criado com `def add`, só que agora o nome `add` não existe mais, mas o nome `var` ainda existe e continua apontando para o objeto original.

O mesmo vale para o segundo caso, pois números inteiros também são objetos. Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types), todo valor em Python é representado por objetos: "*All data in a Python program is represented by objects*".